# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_versions' from 'matplotlib._version'

Tags: numpy, opencv, matplotlib, python-3.7, importerror

When doing my imports:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import opencv_wrapper as cvw
```

I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/bw/fb7g3vhj2ln41zrg3v5ynnn40000gn/T/ipykernel_96862/883562467.py in <module>
      1 # import the necessary packages
      2 import cv2
----> 3 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import opencv_wrapper as cvw

/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>
    114 # Get the version from the _version.py versioneer file. For a git checkout,
    115 # this is computed based on the number of commits since the last tag.
--> 116 from ._version import get_versions
    117 __version__ = str(get_versions()['version'])
    118 del get_versions

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_versions' from 'matplotlib._version' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_version.py)
```

I'm using:
matplotlib 3.4.3
numpy 1.16.2
opencv-python 4.0.0.21
opencv-wrapper 0.2.3
python 3.7.13

Due to the opencv wrapper these are the versions I need to use.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall but the error persists. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As I've said: Due to opencv-wrapper, these are the required versions os opencv & numpy, which in turn require this version of matplotlib.